# Google Charts API: Incorrect date being displayed

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a strange issue that I'm baffled with but I'm sure someone in here will know what I'm doing wrong.  All my dates are displaying incorrectly (i.e. June is displaying July, July is displaying August)

My code here:

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawVisualization() {

    var chartTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    chartTable.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    chartTable.addColumn('number', 'Sell');
    chartTable.addColumn('number', 'GP');
    chartTable.addRows(6);

    chartTable.setValue(0, 0, new Date( 2011, 06, 22 ));
    chartTable.setValue(0, 1, 1316.90);
    chartTable.setValue(0, 2, 456.05);
    chartTable.setValue(1, 0, new Date( 2011, 06, 21 ));
    chartTable.setValue(1, 1, 1793.70);
    chartTable.setValue(1, 2, 531.10);
    chartTable.setValue(2, 0, new Date( 2011, 06, 20 ));
    chartTable.setValue(2, 1, 13559.25);
    chartTable.setValue(2, 2, 1337.75);
    chartTable.setValue(3, 0, new Date( 2011, 06, 17 ));
    chartTable.setValue(3, 1, 3034.15);
    chartTable.setValue(3, 2, 892.30);
    chartTable.setValue(4, 0, new Date( 2011, 06, 16 ));
    chartTable.setValue(4, 1, 568.45);
    chartTable.setValue(4, 2, 175.05);
    chartTable.setValue(5, 0, new Date( 2011, 06, 15 ));
    chartTable.setValue(5, 1, 7203.85);
    chartTable.setValue(5, 2, 1343.45);

    var date_formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'EEE, MMM-d'});
    date_formatter.format(chartTable, 0); // Apply format to first column of table

    var currency_formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '$'});
    currency_formatter.format(chartTable, 1); // Apply format to second column of chart
    currency_formatter.format(chartTable, 2); // Apply format to third column of chart

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(chartTable, {width: 900, height: 400, title: 'Sales Summary',
        vAxis: {maxValue: 20000, format: '$##,###', viewWindowMode: 'maximized'},
        hAxis: {direction: -1}
    });
```

Is displaying all data correctly EXCEPT the date - instead of displaying on the chart June it is displaying July??? Same days of the month but the month is wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The javascript Date object begins counting months at 00, so 00 = January, 01 = February, etc... So when you construct your dates using '06' in the month field, it's actually the 7th month, or July

Comment: just found that while looking further into Date Object!  just to make it difficult!!!

Comment: come on now, every programmer knows you start counting at 0 ;)

Comment: yes, but the days of the month start counting with 1 so there are exceptions!  I'm getting date from MySQL using DATE_FORMAT with %m - there does not appear to be a method to get what I need - I'm going to have -1 each month! is there a better way (BTW - it would be a stretch for me to classify myself as a "programmer" :)

Comment: haha good point...always exceptions to the rule! you're right, you'll probably just have to do a -1 every time you grab the month... i can't think of a better way!

Comment: Just ran into this because C# DateTime.Now.Month returns 12 for December, so javascript was thinking it was next year already.  Was stuck on this bug for too long.  Time travel has a way of making me tired.

Answer (score 2):

To build on wolv2012 response, I just ran into this problem: JS month-counting system is zero-based while MySQL returns months numbers between 1 and 12.

My date being formatted in SQL before it goes in the Javascript `new Date(...)`, I compensate for this by appending a "-1" to my month number while still in SQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(jobs.date, '%Y, %m-1, %d') ...
```

While this looks a little DIY to me, it definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this thread helped me, thank you! I know this post is very old, but it was relevant to me, so in case it helps someone else in the future:

My fix for SQL Server was:`SELECT cast(DATEADD(month,-1,[mydate]) as newdate` And actually, for the format for the google annotation chart I was using, I had to format like this: 
`replace(cast(DATEADD(month,-1,[mydate]) as date),'-', ',')  as dateforJSON`